# Chrome Cordova App plugin access

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cordova, google-chrome-app

I am developing a chrome app to be translated with mobile chrome app ex. cca. The documentation says I will be able to have access to apache cordovas plugins. Im having issues getting the contacts api to work and im not sure of a few things. Does anyone have good tutorial or documentation on how to make it work? I have specific questions below.

1) Do I have to run `cordova` commands to include the project folders as specified in [this documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface)

2) To test the plugin examples in the cordova webpage do I have to write them into my google app before I translate them with cca or do I have to write them to each device after translation. ex permissions and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `cca` will forward cordova commands to `cordova` internally, so if you expect `cordova plugin add` to work, so should `cca plugin add`.  However, sticking to `cca` exclusively is a better idea, since we make sure to use a compatible version of the tools, set up your environment properly, and run some chrome app specific checks outside of cordova hooks.

2) I prefer to use a single application codebase for both desktop and all mobile targets.  I do this by creating `cca` projects with `--link-to=` argument to share a single codebase.  Then I use feature detection to make sure I only use features which are available, i.e.

```
if (typeof window.cordova !== 'undefined') {
  // use contacts plugin
}
```

However, if you prefer not to directly share the codebase with your desktop app, then do not use `--link-to=` and use `--copy-from=` instead (and synchronize edits however you like).

In either case, you should be exclusively editing what is inside your cca project root `www/` folder, and not editing what is inside the `platform/` directory.